# Not receiving push notifications on iOS

Tags: swift, firebase

I set up a Firebase Cloud Messaging client app on iOS but the I got this message

```
 APNS device token not set before retrieving FCM Token for Sender ID '********'. Notifications to this FCM Token will not be delivered over APNS.Be sure to re-retrieve the FCM token once the APNS device token is set.
```

And this method is called didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError and I got this:

```
Unable to register for remote notifications: no se encontró ninguna cadena de autorización “aps-environment” para la app
```

The problem is that application won't receiving messages, none get called (only didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError) also I can't get fcm, I added this methods in app delegate:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate{
    var window: UIWindow?
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
          let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
          let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
          UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
          application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
    }
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
          print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }
        print(userInfo)
    }
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
          print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }
        print(userInfo)
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
      print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
      print("APNs token retrieved: \(deviceToken)")
    }

}
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
      withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
      let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

      if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
      }
      print(userInfo)
      completionHandler([[.alert, .sound]])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
      let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
      if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
      }
      print(userInfo)

      completionHandler()
    }
}
extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
  func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(String(describing: fcmToken))")
    let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken ?? ""]
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
  }
}
```

Comment: Unless you list all the steps you have taken, it's hard for others to find out what the cause of your problem is.

Comment: in this most common problem faces is `FCM Token` override so check if fcm token called twice token will be change so you can't get the notification.